# Why does the default year of a new instance of the Date class equal -4712?

Tags: ruby

Running:

```
require 'date'
y = Date.new
puts "default year is #{y.year}"
```

Output:

```
default year is -4712
```

Is there any particular reason why the year of a Date object defaults to **-4712**? I thought perhaps there's a technical (or conventional) reason. I have googled this and looked it up on the Ruby documentation (2.2.3) and I can't see an answer as to *why*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The day of January 1, 4713 BC is the beginning of the [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), from Wiki:

> The **Julian Day Number (JDN)** is the integer assigned to a whole solar day in the Julian day count starting from noon Greenwich Mean Time, with Julian day number 0 assigned to the day starting at noon on January 1, 4713 BC, proleptic Julian calendar (November 24, 4714 BC, in the proleptic Gregorian calendar), a date at which three multi-year cycles started and which preceded any historical dates. For example, the Julian day number for the day starting at 12:00 UT on January 1, 2000, was 2,451,545.

The year of this day, is 4713 BC, or technically `-4712`.

Comment: It makes sense that the default year refers to **4713 BC** as you pointed out and which I had no idea about so thanks. But in order to give a more complete answer, I feel that you need to expand on what you mean by **technically**.  I think you need to add to your answer that the _Date class_ uses [Astronomical year numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_year_numbering) which includes the _year 0_. So the _year 1 BC_ becomes _year 0_, the _year 2 BC_ becomes _year -1_, the _year 3 BC_ becomes _year -2_ and so on. Therefore the **year 4713 BC** becomes the **year -4712**.